# Made from flowers?

Tags: ingredients, fermentation

What alcohol is made from the solely from the nectar of flowers (with no hops in it) like honey suckle? Where could I buy that? Pull a honey suckle flower inside there is about two drops of nectar collect enough to ferment.

Comment: almost all Real beer is made with hop flowers as the bittering and flavouring additive, does that count?

Comment: I would also like to get this question cleaned up. It's not obvious what you are asking from the question but is obvious when you open up the question detail.

Comment: Are you asking for alcohol that is made *only* from flower nectar?  (You said "solely".)  Or do you mean made with flower nectar as the only flavoring agent (but still grain for beer, grapes for wine, honey for mead, etc)?  Please [edit] to clarify what you're asking.  Thanks.

Comment: Like I argued below, Honey = Nectar. The bees don't transform it in anyway, they just transport it back to the hive. I don't know what else you need for an answer. And NO, nobody is pulling honeysuckle stamens by hand to collect the nectar. If you think there are a bunch of little old ladies in Portugal pulling honeysuckle stamens all day long, you can forget about it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are no alcoholic beverages made from the "nectar" of flowers per se. It would be very difficult/expensive to collect 100% flower nectar straight from flowers in sufficient quantities to make a beverage. Having said that, [honey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey) is essentially flower nectar collected by bees and regurgitated in the hive as a future food source. You can enjoy fermented Honey as [Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mead) in a wide variety of flavors and flower varieties. Bees store the nectar in a "honey stomach" so there is no digestion of the nectar. [Read in more detail here:](http://ucanr.edu/blogs/blogcore/postdetail.cfm?postnum=15512)

> "Although many sources refer to the honey bee crop as the 'honey
>   stomach,' it is not a place where consumed foods are being digested in
>   honey bees."
>
> In their book, Honey Bee Biology and Beekeeping, authors Dewey Caron
>   and Lawrence John "Larry" Connor define the honey stomach as a a
>   "honey sac."
>
> It's "an enlargement of the posterior end of the esophagus in the bee
>   abdomen in which the bee carries the nectar from flower to hive."
>
> Bee vomit? No way. It's where nectar is stored. It's not a stomach as
>   we know it.

As mentioned before, beer is made with a flower called hops. There are many other beers and meads flavored with dried flowers.

As for where to buy Mead, you can most likely find it any decent beer/wine/liquor store and easily by searching the web.

Comment: it is close to the answer I'm looking for. 1 up from me. I revised the question.

Comment: Honey = Nectar so the closest thing you'll ever get is Mead.

Answer (score 4):

There is a beer called Honeysuckle Smash by [Three Brothers Brewing](http://threebrothersbrewing.co.uk/)

[image]

This is a golden ale made in North Yorkshire and you can buy it straight from their website [here](http://threebrothersbrewing.co.uk/product/honeysuckle-smash/).

Comment: it is close to the answer I'm looking for. 1 up from me. I revised the question.

Answer (score 1):

Enlightenment wines meadery makes a dandelion wine- it’s also made with honey but there are dozens of flowers in every bottle. [EWM site](http://enlightenmentwines.com)

Answer (score 0):

You can tie of the end of banana's in flower. Come back & drink them for a kind of wine. Natives do. 1 taste was enough for me. Or buy the buds at the market. That are cut of trees so it produces larger banana's. Dandalion can be used to make a wine. Very good. Just stuff the jug full of flowers. Ferment , filter, drink.